# How can I tell what user Jenkins is running as?

Tags: linux, jenkins, bitnami

I have a bitnami Jenkins VM, how do I tell what user Jenkins is running as? I suspect it is Tomcat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use `ps` to get the uid of the process, and grep for that in /etc/passwd

Comment: That seems to return PID

Comment: used ps -u returned user names

Answer (score 12):

If you have access to the gui, you can go to "manage jenkins" > "system information" and look for "user.name".

Answer (score 3):

You could also create a Jenkins job containing a shell script box with the "whoami" command.

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to see under which process your Jenkins server works on:

```
ps axufwwww | grep 'jenkins\|java' -
```

To interpret the results, look for:

```
jenkins   1087  0.0  0.0  18740   396 ?        S    08:00   0:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=jenkins
jenkins   1088  1.6 20.7 3600900 840116 ?      Sl   08:00   2:12  \_ /usr/bin/java
```

1087 and 1088 are the PIDs. They might differ for you.

Answer (score 1):

`ps aux | grep '/usr/bin/daemon' | grep 'jenkins' | awk {'print $1'}`

The command will show running processes, then grep for a process running as a daemon that includes the string 'jenkins'. Finally, get the first row of the piped output which is the user that is running Jenkins.