# Please explain to me how Jenkins run without a process visible?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

**I'm trying to figure out what user Jenkins is running as.**

I found [How can I tell what user Jenkins is running as?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733671/how-can-i-tell-what-user-jenkins-is-running-as) where the selected answer suggests to do a `$ps -u` but the output is simply

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
pierre   16444  1.0  0.0  29656  5092 pts/2    Ss   10:22   0:00 bash
pierre   16455  0.0  0.0  44432  3384 pts/2    R+   10:22   0:00 ps -u
```

I have Jenkins installed and running at localhost:8080 and I can log into it from a diff box - So I assume a Jenkins process should be running somewhere... Meanwhile the default wiki mentions that Jenkins creates a default User "Jenkins" to run processes - but I can't seem to log into it using `$su - Jenkins`

=> How do I figure out which user Jenkins is running as? Am I misunderstanding the processes/Users way to work?

Thanks for guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that Jenkins usually runs as its own user Jenkins. You should be able to see the respective process by executing

```
ps -aux | grep jenkins
```

It is not unusual that you cannot log in as such a special purpose user, if you want to call it like that. A reason for that might be that the jenkins user has no (valid) login shell.

Comment: I could only see 1 process using `top` - but using `ps -aux | grep jenkins` I can catch 4 processes, all of them with jenkins as the user. Is there a different command to verify which user Jenkins is running as? What if it was a diff user and I didn't know which it was, how would I go about finding out?